# raise error if not header found(csv files)

Tags: python

Reading CSV files. I want to raise error message if there is no any header from following list. It must be atleast one header in csv file.
Headers are
`age sex city`. I'm trying like this. thanks

```
with open('data.csv') as f:
  cf = csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=['city'])
  for row in cf:
    print row['city']
```

Comment: You'll need to indent after the `with` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
import csv

with open('data.csv', 'rb') as inf:
    cf = csv.reader(inf)

    header = cf.next()
    if header != ['Age', 'Sex', 'City']:
        print "No header found"
    else:
        for row in cf:
            print row[2]
```

Comment: quick response. Thanks alot :-)

Comment: Its matching all the list. I don't want to match all the headers.is it possible?

Comment: @Richard: I am sorry, I don't understand what you mean. The columns may be in a different order? You only want to return the 'City' column? Something like that?

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding of the question, the header check needs to pass if any headers are found. Otherwise it should raise an exception.

```
import csv

with open('data.csv','rb') as f:
    fieldnames = ['age','sex','city']
    cf = csv.DictReader(f)
    headers = cf.fieldnames

    if len(set(fieldnames).intersection(set(headers))) == 0:
        raise csv.Error("CSV Error: Invalid headers: %s" % str(headers))

    for row in cf:
        city = row['city'] if 'city' in headers else "N/A"
        sex = row['sex'] if 'sex' in headers else "N/A"
        age = row['age'] if 'age' in headers else "N/A"
        print "city: " + city + ", sex: " + sex + ", age: " + age
```